# Pine Script - Tradingview -Need Delayed a Sequence of Triggers to happen not on the same bar in order to execute

Tags: triggers, pine-script, tradingview-api

Still new to Pine Script.  Writing a bollinger band script and I need two triggers, where one trigger needs to happen 1st (close price crosses upper band) and set a variable to true and does not change until the 2 second trigger (exits me from trade) which is when price crosses middle band then will execute and close out trade.

The triggers won't be happening on the same bar.

I think I'm looking for the right variable that I can set true and retains its value through multiple bars until I change it.  Like I said I'm new and looking for quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable for this purpose with the `var` keyword. It will hold it's value across bars until you modify it.

```
var bool upperBandCrossed = false
bool exitCond = false

if open < upperBB and close > upperBB
     upperBandCrossed := true
if open > basis and close < basis and upperBandCrossed
     exitCond := true
     upperBandCrossed := false
```

Comment: Thanks, Greatly Appreciated!!